# Hibernate criteria one-to-many distinct result

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have one `person` table. A `person` might have multiple `kids`, which are also persons.
Thus, there is a one to many relationship between the person table.

I want to get all persons, which have at least one son `(sex=male)`. I do this by following criteria:

```
List personsWithSon = sess.createCriteria(Person.class)
     .createAlias("kids", "k")
     .add( Restrictions.eq("k.sex", "male") )
     .list();
```

This is fine, as long as there is only one son. If there are e.g. three sons, the person is returned three times. But I just need the person one time. How can I do a distinct over the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to:

```
List personsWithSon = sess.createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("kids", "k").add(Restrictions.eq("k.sex", "male")).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I was working with "Projections.distinct" before, but that didn't seem to do any good and led into errors.